# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'PolyCollection'

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, audio, librosa

I am trying to plot an audio file using `librosa.display.waveplot(y,sr)`

my code:

```
import librosa.display
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[1])
y, sr = librosa.load("Audiofilepath")
ax1.plot(librosa.display.waveplot(y, sr))
```

I got the result plotted. Even though I am getting the below error message

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'PolyCollection'
```

I explored in StackOverflow with the above error message, Results available for `numbers, period, nanType`. but not for `PolyCollection`.

If any experts in `librosa` plotting, please guide me to avoid this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are following a wrong documentation. The documentation of `librosa.display.waveplot()` can be found at https://librosa.org/doc/latest/generated/librosa.display.waveplot.html.

`librosa.display.waveplot()` itself doesn't plot anything, you have to call `plt.show()` to visualize it.

```py
import librosa
import librosa.display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()

y, sr = librosa.load("1.mp3")
librosa.display.waveplot(y, sr)

plt.title('Example of librosa.display.waveplot')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The return type of `librosa.display.waveplot()` is `matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection`. The parameter type of [matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html) can be *array-like or scalar*.

However you passed `PolyCollection` to `matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot`. That's why you got `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'PolyCollection'` raised by `ax1.plot(librosa.display.waveplot(y, sr))`.